# Can I access 'unseen' message status via Graph/FQL API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension, facebook-fql

I'm developing a Chrome extension for message notifications from FB inbox.

The Facebook itself has a Chrome extension, which works well and notifies only of unseen messages. However, I can't reproduce it's behaviour without using `/me/inbox` connection which has the `unseen` attribute on message thread. The drawback is a rather heavy response (all messages in the inbox + metadata).

Also, it's an undocumented property. I can see total number of unseen messages by using FQL table `unified_thread_count`. And I wish I could also see the message `unseen` status somewhere.

If this can't be done, what way can I mimic the FB's chrome notification extension behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `fields=` querystring parameter to limit the fields returned from the query
https://graph.facebook.com/me/inbox/?fields=id,unseen&access_token=

Comment: Sorry, it was Graph API explorer who added metadata=1 to the request.